# Accelerate a pandas operation involving several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, accelerate

Hello everyone

For a school project, I am stuck with the duration of an operation with Pandas Dataframe.

I have one dataframe df which shape is (250 000 000, 200). This dataframe contains values of variable describing the behaviours of sensors on a machine.
 They are organized by 'Cycle' (everytime the machine begins a new cycle, this variable is incremented by one). And in this cycle, 'CycleTime' describes the position of the row within the 'Cycle'.

In the 'mean' DataFrame, I compute the mean of each variables group by the 'CycleTime'

The 'anomaly_matrix' DataFrame represents the global anomaly of each cycle which is the sum of the square difference of each rows belonging to the Cycle with the mean of corresponding CycleTime.

An example of my code is below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cycle': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'CycleTime': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], 'variable1': [0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25], 'variable2':[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2], 'variable3': [100, 5000, 200, 900, 100, 2000, 300, 300]})
mean = df.drop(['Cycle'], axis = 1).groupby("CycleTime").agg('mean')
anomali_matrix = df.drop(['CycleTime'], axis = 1).groupby("Cycle").agg('mean')
anomaly_matrix = anomali_matrix - anomali_matrix

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cycle = row["Cycle"]
    time = row["CycleTime"]
    anomaly_matrix.loc[cycle] += (row - mean.loc[time])**2


>>>anomaly_matrix
   variable1    variable2   variable3
Cycle           
0   0.047014    0.25       1.116111e+07
1   0.023681    0.25       3.917778e+06
2   0.018889    0.00       2.267778e+06
```

This calculation for my (250 000 000, 200) DataFrame last 6 hours, it is due to anomaly_matrix.loc[cycle] += (row - mean.loc[time])**2

I tried to improve by using an apply function but I do not succeed in adding other DataFrame in that apply function. Same thing trying to vectorize pandas.

Do you have any idea how to accelerate this process ? Thanks

Comment: Another name for "sum of the squared difference from the mean" is `variance`.  Perhaps there are some relevant optimized functions?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.var.html

Comment: `anomaly_matrix = anomali_matrix - anomali_matrix` is correct?

Comment: anomaly_matrix = anomali_matrix - anomali_matrix is certainly a bad way to set all values of my dataframe to 0

Comment: I tried with optimized function but I did not get good results for the moment. I am going to persevere in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Cycle', 'CycleTime'])

mean = df1.sub(df1.groupby('CycleTime').transform('mean'))**2
df2 = mean.groupby('Cycle').sum()
print (df2)
       variable1  variable2     variable3
Cycle                                    
0       0.047014       0.25  1.116111e+07
1       0.023681       0.25  3.917778e+06
2       0.018889       0.00  2.267778e+06
```

Comment: @laurentBimont - I use your solution, only omit `anomaly_matrix = anomali_matrix - anomali_matrix`, because it dont have sense.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I update my post with the result of anomaly_matrix. It does not seem to be equal to your df2. I am going to study more your solution to figure out if it can work.

Comment: @laurentBimont - thank you, then solution is more simplify ;)